# List of values to dictionary

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a list of values to a list of dictionary's based on my set keys. I tried the following but i'm loosing all the other values because of the duplicate key names.

```
>>> values = ['XS ', '1', 'S ', '10', 'M ', '1', 'L ', '10', 'XL ', '10']
>>> keys = ['size', 'stock'] * (len(values) / 2)
>>> result = dict(zip(keys, values))
>>> print result
{'stock': '10', 'size': 'XL '}
```

What i'm trying to achieve is a list of the dicts like below. How can I achieve this?

```
[{'stock': '10', 'size': 'XL '}, {'stock': '10', 'size': 'L'}, ......]
```

Comment: It seems silly to base your keys on the amount of stock, as that will change often.  Wouldn't it be better to have a single dict keyed on the size ( 'XS', 'S', etc) and put the stock amount as the value?

Comment: wouldn't it make more sense to have the size as the key and stock as the value? then you would do `result = dict(zip(values[::2], values[1::2]))`

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen yes good idea.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen you should make this an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension like following:

```
>>> values = ['XS ', '1', 'S ', '10', 'M ', '1', 'L ', '10', 'XL ', '10']
>>> [{'size':i, 'stock':j} for i, j in zip(values[0::2], values[1::2])]
[{'stock': '1', 'size': 'XS '}, {'stock': '10', 'size': 'S '}, {'stock': '1', 'size': 'M '}, {'stock': '10', 'size': 'L '}, {'stock': '10', 'size': 'XL '}]
```

Note that in this case you don't have to multiply the keys.

Comment: Good idea, not multiplying the keys. Thanks really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the point of using a `dict` is to associate unique keys to associated values, you were originally trying to associate `size: ...` and `stock: ...` for each item but why not link the size to stock?  In that case you would simply do:

```
result = dict(zip(values[::2], values[1::2]))
```

or without needing slicing:

```
value_iter = iter(values)
result = dict(zip(value_iter, value_iter))
```

This grabs two elements from the list at a time.

This way you still know that a given key in the dict is the size and the associated value is the stock for that size.

Comment: Oh that was more simpler than i thought. Thanks :)